# using openMP for OpenGL 3D rendering

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, openmp

Is it efficient to use *OpenMP* in CG(*OpenGL*) for rendering 3D polygon images in case of animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no benefits in trying to queue up rendering commands to the GPU in parallel. Rendering happens in parallel on the GPU already and sending in the commands in parallel just creates a lot of overhead in the driver which must check for synchronization points in the command stream and may need to reorder things.

Also multithreaded OpenGL operation is tricky to get right.

Comment: Agree, also what I was going to say was trying to allow multiple CPU threads to access the PCIe bus at the same time out to a graphics card will most likely be no better than a single thread as only one thread will truly be able to access that IO bus at a time.

Comment: @trumpetlicks: With PCIe it's not that bad, as PCIe does all its operations in so called "transactions" with a specific packet length (well actually there's a whole set of lengths, but they're quite short actually). Multiple threads can interleave those transactions without problem. So it's mostly a bandwidth problem. But in any well written OpenGL program you'd upload geometry to GPU RAM first anyway and then trigger a whole rendering batch with a single command.

Comment: Totally agree about the packeting (and letting the GPU do the parallelism of the geometry, etc...), however the bandwidth (+ overhead) of the PCIe bus is SOOOOOOOO much slower than even 1 core (RAM is much faster than PCIe and it still can stall a single thread if and when it has to pager out to memory), that having multiple cores (or threads in the case of HT) try to access that bus would essentially keep most threads in blocked states most of the time. It is much better to collect all data to send to the GPU and try to send it in fewer but larger packets (thus less overhead).

Answer (score 0):

trying to allow multiple CPU threads to access the PCIe bus at the same time out to a graphics card will most likely be no better than a single thread as only one thread will truly be able to access that IO bus at a time.